# Is there a way to prevent someone from screen recording ZOOM meetings from an outside software?

Tags: security, screen-recording, audio-recording, zoom

Is there a way to prevent someone from screen-recording your Zoom courses using a any screen recorder?

If not, is there a solution like this that works for something other than Zoom or maybe an already built-in feature in an alternative to Zoom that prevents someone from screen recording without permission?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, I have completely no idea how you imagine such software. Even if you somehow managed to block software recording, which is close to impossible (Zoom would need to be modified), how would you prevent a good hardware camera from recording it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such software, or at least none that works 100%. If your viewer is determined enough and has enough technical knowledge, they will be able to record your ZOOM meeting.

Unless you can control the device that your viewers have at hand, they are free to do anything with the video stream they receive, for instance record the network packets or video frames.

And even if you control their hardware and software, they could even set up a video camera that records their screen, which of course you have no way to prevent.